# How to replace subset of string from pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, string, replace

Below is my input string

```
df =   text                   codes
       anesthesia code        99921
       aretic closure         75454
       nyopia                 75633
       right atrial           89732

string =  However, when performed anesthesia code with a formal report, this service may be considered a significant, separately identifiable, and if nyopia, a separately reportable service.
```

In input string if we get any text from text column then we can replace with that perticular code from code column.

I want output like

```
output =  However, when performed 99921 with a formal report, this service may be considered a significant, separately identifiable, and if 75633, a separately reportable service.
```

So how I can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Using a single regular expression that matches all of the texts should be quite efficient:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "text": ["anesthesia code", "aretic closure", "nyopia", "right atrial"],
        "codes": [99921, 75454, 75633, 89732],
    }
)

# Generate a mapping of text to code
text_to_codes = {text: str(code) for text, code in zip(df["text"], df["codes"])}
# Generate a regexp that will match any `text`s
match_re = re.compile("|".join(re.escape(t) for t in text_to_codes))

string = """
However, when performed anesthesia code with a formal report,
this service may be considered a significant, separately identifiable,
and if nyopia, a separately reportable service.
"""

# Run the regexp on the string, replacing texts with what we find in the mapping
output = match_re.sub(lambda m: text_to_codes[m.group(0)], string)

print(output)
```

This outputs

```
However, when performed 99921 with a formal report,
this service may be considered a significant, separately identifiable,
and if 75633, a separately reportable service.
```

If you add `flags=re.I` to the `compile` call, this becomes case-insensitive too.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use pandas? If not, just put the data in a dictionary.

```
string =  'However, when performed anesthesia code with a formal report, this service may be considered a significant, separately identifiable, and if nyopia, a separately reportable service.'

dict = {
    'anesthesia code': '99921',
    'aretic closure': '75454',
    'nyopia' : '75633',
    'right atrial' : '89732'
}

for key in dict:
    if key in string:
        string = string.replace(key, dict[key])

print(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```py
d = {
    'anesthesia code': '99921',
    'aretic closure': '75454',
    'nyopia' : '75633',
    'right atrial' : '89732'
}

print(f"However, when performed {d['anesthesia code']} with a formal report, this service may be considered a significant, separately identifiable, and if {d['nyopia']}, a separately reportable service.")
```